# asdf:test-system from a Makefile doesn't return an error return code

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

My unit tests run fine, but the `make test` target won't return an error code when the tests fail (`echo $?` is 0) (it does when there is a lisp error).

This is not good for a CI system.

My main system definition ends with `in-order-to`:

```
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "mysystem/test"))))
```

My test system has a `perform` one:

```
  :perform (test-op (o s)
                    (uiop:symbol-call '#:mysestem.test '#:test-all)))
```

where `test-all` is a function that runs Fiveam test suites with  `run! 'test-suite`.

The make target:

```
test:
  # (with proper indentation…)
  $(LISP) --non-interactive \
    --eval "(asdf:load-asd \""$(ASD_PATH)"\")" \
    --eval "(ql:quickload :mysystem/test)" \
    --eval "(asdf:test-system \"mysystem\")"
```

Note that follownig ASDF's [best practices](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/doc/best_practices.md#trivial-testing-definition) in doing

```
                    (symbol-call :fiveam #':run! :test-suite)))
```

errors out with "The function :run! is undefined."

How do we do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: `ASDF:TEST-SYSTEM` doesn't kill the image, so it doesn't affect the exit code one way or another. How to exit with an error code is implementation dependent, but uiop has `UIOP:QUIT`.

Comment: That actually makes sense, since we can call it from the repl. So I'm trying things like `--eval "(unless (asdf:test-system \"mysystem\") (uiop:quit 1))"` with no success so far. I have a failing test and still `0`, but the last output is `Didn't run anything...huh?` so maybe fiveam doesn't return `nil` here.

Comment: Now I have a clean output with one failing test, but still `echo $?` = 0.

Comment: The return value of `ASDF:TEST-SYSTEM` doesn't indicate test success/failure. The manual suggests signalling a condition from the [test-op](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#test_002dop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as [@jskiiski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747548/jkiiski) points out, that `asdf:test-system` returns true regardless of what the `test-op` returned.

I'm using rove instead of fiveam, and `rove:run` actually *does* return `nil` if the tests failed. So my workaround is to call it directly (instead of `asdf:test-system`), and use `uiop:quit` to get the right return code:

```
sbcl --non-interactive \
     --eval '(ql:quickload :mysystem)' \
     --eval '(asdf:load-system :rove)' \
     --eval '(uiop:quit (if (rove:run "mysystem/tests") 0 1))'
```

I decided against trying to fiddle that logic into `test-op` because I use `asdf:test-system` interactively most of the time.

Can't think of any solution that doesn't feel like a workaround though. `asdf:test-system` just passing along whatever `test-op` returns (or something to that effect) seems like the only proper fix.

Comment: This is it. And a how-to with fiveam: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/testing.html#running-tests-on-the-terminal

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be typos:

- `'#:mysestem.test` ⇒ `'#:mysystem.test`
- `#':run!` ⇒ `'#:run!`

Comment: The `run` one is a real one. I put it the name of a test suite (as in `:test-suite`) but it doesn't run anything :/ "Didn't run anything...huh?"